# /proc/cpuinfo security

Tags: permissions, security, cpuinfo

I find that some applications want to check /proc/cpuinfo but don't have access

This is on my server running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, the permissions are:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 May  2 14:35 /proc/cpuinfo
```

My desktop is also running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS but the permissions are different and less restrictive:

```
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 May  2 15:37 /proc/cpuinfo
```

Which one is correct? Are they restrictive on my server for a reason? Can I update my server's permissions to be the same as my desktop or is that dangerous?

Comment: `-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 29 14:31 /proc/cpuinfo`   is on a 20.04 server of mine

Comment: `-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 May  2 08:07 /proc/cpuinfo` is on a 20.04 server of mine. `-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 May  2 08:08 /proc/cpuinfo` is on a debian server of mine. It should not be a writeable file, as far as I know.

Comment: /proc can provide info, e.g. `cat /proc/cpuinfo`. ... /proc is an empty virtual filesystem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646784/why-the-size-of-proc-directory-is-shown-empty

Comment: feels like you have something in your startup manually setting the permission